# OpenMPI running with 32-bit and 64-bit processors, parallel run crash

Tags: parallel-processing, crash, mpi, 32bit-64bit

This pertains to MPI with 2 computers running 64-bit cpus and a third machine running a 32-bit cpu. All the computers have the same exact locations for the `lib` and `bin` and all of them have the exact same bashrc along with the same folder where the executables are stored. The SSH connection works the same for both the 64-bit machine and the 32-bit machine. The server is a 64-bit machine. I locally compiled the executable on the 32-bit machine (seen as ([K7ASA:1555])) and it worked on it but when I tried to run it in parallel remotely, I got this message.

```
mpirun -host 10.42.0.163,10.42.0.72,10.42.0.68 ./mpi_quad-1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
  --> Returned "(null)" (-43) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[K7ASA:1555] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[40577,1],2]
  Exit code:    1
```

Here's the output for

`mpirun -host 10.42.0.163,10.42.0.72,10.42.0.68 --tag-output uname -a`

```
[1,0]<stdout>:Linux verthex-Lenovo-V570 4.15.0-38-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 20:16:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[1,1]<stdout>:Linux verthex-HP-Pavilion-zv5000-DP299AV 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[1,2]<stdout>:Linux verthex-K7ASA 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:58:23 UTC 2018 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

`mpirun -host 10.42.0.163,10.42.0.72,10.42.0.68 --tag-output file mpi_quad-1`

```
[1,0]<stdout>:mpi_quad-1: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=a7aa397b9a339ae464201270a065fa7037721016, not stripped
[1,1]<stdout>:mpi_quad-1: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=a7aa397b9a339ae464201270a065fa7037721016, not stripped
[1,2]<stdout>:mpi_quad-1: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=a7aa397b9a339ae464201270a065fa7037721016, not stripped
```

`mpirun -host 10.42.0.163,10.42.0.72,10.42.0.68 --tag-output ldd mpi_quad-1`

```
[1,0]<stdout>:  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc091eb000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libmpi.so.40 => /usr/local/lib/libmpi.so.40 (0x00007fbda7934000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbda7717000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbda734d000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libopen-rte.so.40 => /usr/local/lib/libopen-rte.so.40 (0x00007fbda7096000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libopen-pal.so.40 => /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.40 (0x00007fbda6d8b000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbda6b83000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbda687a000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbda7c2e000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbda6660000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbda645c000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007fbda6251000)
[1,0]<stdout>:  libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fbda604e000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  [1,1]<stdout>:linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcfcdd0000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  [1,1]<stdout>:libmpi.so.40 => /usr/local/lib/libmpi.so.40 (0x00007f59231b5000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  [1,1]<stdout>:libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5922f96000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  [1,1]<stdout>:libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5922ba5000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  [1,1]<stdout>:libopen-rte.so.40 => /usr/local/lib/libopen-rte.so.40 (0x00007f59228f0000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  libopen-pal.so.40 => /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.40 (0x00007f59225e1000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f59223d9000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  [1,1]<stdout>:libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f592203b000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f59234ca000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5921e1e000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5921c1a000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f5921a0f000)
[1,1]<stdout>:  [1,1]<stdout>:libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f592180c000)
[1,2]<stdout>:  [1,2]<stdout>:not a dynamic executable
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[45618,1],2]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: are you trying to run the same app `mpi_quad` on all the machines ? if yes, it means the 32 bits MPI library must be installed on the 64 bits OS. Is that so ? First, I suggest you simply run `mpi_quad-1` on all your machines (without `mpirun` aka singleton mode) to confirm all the dependencies can be found.

Comment: I see, but what about compiling the mpi_quad on the 64-bit machines with mpicc, doesn't that too need to be 32-bit , along with gcc? Basically all of the computers run the code fine separately and when I try to run the two 64-bit machines in parallel then there's no problem, just the 32-bit part is bad.

Comment: I do not understand how your environment is configured, and you'd rather describe it in the question. which binary (e.g. 32 or 64 bits) are you trying to run on the 64 bits OS ? which Open MPI library (e.g. 32 or 64 bits) is installed on the 64 bits OS ? Are your app and library installed on a shared filesystem ?

Comment: Right. My environment on the 64-bit cpu machines are 64 bit MPI,GCC,g++, etc. My environment on the 32-bit machines is all 32-bit as well, GCC,G++ and MPI was complied within the 32-bit environment.

Comment: if you are trying to use a 32 bits binary with a 64 bits MPI library, then that won't work ... I still do not understand how your environment is configured, can you run `mpirun -host 10.42.0.163,10.42.0.72,10.42.0.68 --tag-output uname -a`, `mpirun -host 10.42.0.163,10.42.0.72,10.42.0.68 --tag-output file mpi_quad-1` and `mpirun -host 10.42.0.163,10.42.0.72,10.42.0.68 --tag-output ldd mpi_quad-1` and edit your question ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I added what you asked for, thanks for explaining things so far. I should've realized that I could simply use 32-bit MPI on all the machines as I use that for many years with Windows XP 32-bit on one of those machines. I've decided to use the 32-bit version of MPI on all the machines as that seems to work. I wonder if the upper half of the 64-bit CPU will be utilized if I do this or is that under-utilization. It doesn't matter, I'm experimenting right now just for setup, later I'll optimize or get 3 64-bit machines.

Comment: The logs indicate you are trying to run a 64 bits binary on a 32 bits OS, and this is never going to work. One option is to use 32 bits binary and apps everywhere, and an other option is to run 64 bits binary and app on 64 bits OS, and 32 bits binary and app on a 32 bits OS (you might have to `configure --enable-heterogeneous ...` first, but I am not 100% sure). 64 bits is mandatory if a given MPI task requires more than 4G of memory. Otherwise, 32 bits is fine. Keep in mind that most MPI apps are synchronous in a sense the app runs at the speed of the slowest node.

Comment: You should've just answered this below Gilles. I'll mark it as solved for whomever answers it.